# spring boot starter graphql not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I recently started working with `graphql` and found it very intriguing. Since most of my `rest` apps were in `java`, I decided to do a quick setup using the provided [spring boot starter](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot) project by the `graphql-java` team. It comes with `graph-iql` autoconf spring setup, which makes it easier to query `/graphql` endpoint.

After spending a few good hours on the project setup in IDEA, I was able to run the [graphql-sample-app](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot/tree/master/graphql-sample-app). But I think my servlet is still not enabled, and only the `graphiql` endpoint is running, as the default query is returning `404`.

This is `application.yml`:

```
spring:
      application:
               name: graphql-todo-app
server:
      port: 9000

graphql:
      spring-graphql-common:
               clientMutationIdName: clientMutationId
               injectClientMutationId: true
               allowEmptyClientMutationId: false
               mutationInputArgumentName: input
               outputObjectNamePrefix: Payload
               inputObjectNamePrefix: Input
               schemaMutationObjectName: Mutation
      servlet:
             mapping: /graphql
             enabled: true
             corsEnabled: true

graphiql:
    mapping: /graphiql
    enabled: true
```

This is what my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
//    compile(project(":graphql-spring-boot-starter"))
//    compile(project(":graphiql-spring-boot-starter"))
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:3.6.0'

    // to embed GraphiQL tool
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:3.6.0'

    compile "com.embedler.moon.graphql:spring-graphql-common:$LIB_SPRING_GRAPHQL_COMMON_VER"

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

jar.enabled = true
uploadArchives.enabled = false
bintrayUpload.enabled = false
```

After running `gradle build`, I run the generated `jar` file from the terminal. This is what I get on localhost:

[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what's going on without the full code, would you mind creating a sample project and throwing it up on github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue using Spring boot 2.0.0 (M6). Switching back to 1.5.8.RELEASE solved the problem. They're working on the issue, it will be released as soon as there is a non milestone release for Spring boot 2.x

https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot/issues/40

https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot/pull/36

Answer (score 0):

Change to version 1.5.9.RELEASE of the spring-boot-starter-stop and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a very simple GraphQL application that I had made based on an article, when I tested the `http://localhost:8989/graphql` with Postman I got `404 NOT_FOUND` error, in my case the problem was that I was testing the API with a REST POST request call in the Postman, you need to create a new GraphQL request by clicking on `New` button in Postman and then if your application has been launched, automatically accessible API's is displayed, in my case the problem was that.

see the below screenshot:
[image]